# loop only starts filling array half way through

Tags: java

I'm trying to populate an array with random numbers in java but the first half of the array is only populated with "0" regardless of the array size
here's the code responsible for populating the array

```
while (i<fileSizeArray.length)  
    {
        randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * (400 - 100) + 100);   
        fileSizeArray[i] = randomNumber;
        Arrays.sort(fileSizeArray);     
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: there shouldn't be any 0s, I want the number to be between 100 and 400 which they all are beside the first half

Answer (score 2):

```
Arrays.sort(fileSizeArray);
```

You sort the Array inside the loop.

So all the zeroes get sorted to the beginning.

This pushes the random value to the end of the array.

Then you add a new value and all the zeroes get moved to the beginning again and the random value after all the zeroes.

Eventually your overwrite the random values at the end of the array after you process half the numbers.

**The sort should be done outside the loop.**

Answer (score 0):

To fill the array with random numbers, do this

```
    int i=0;
    while (i<fileSizeArray.length)  
    {
        fileSizeArray[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (400 - 100) + 100); 
        i++;
    }
    Arrays.sort(fileSizeArray);
```

start with 0 and increment to fill the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

### Arrays.sort cannot be mixed with a collector

In this case, you are using a collector (fileSizeArray) inside a loop, then in the same loop you sort the collector. This cannot be mixed. You cannot mix a collector with a sort function.

You have an error on Arrays.sort, move it outside the loop.

```
while (i<fileSizeArray.length)  
    {
        randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * (400 - 100) + 100);   
        fileSizeArray[i] = randomNumber;

        i++;
    }

Arrays.sort(fileSizeArray);
```